# No method error is shown when associating ActiveRecords table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying RoR Active Records with Association.
And trying to connect two tables, which is restaurants and restaurant_translations. These are split for multi-language support.

Here's the definition of those two tables.

```
  create_table "restaurant_translations", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id",             limit: 4,     default: 0,  null: false
    t.integer  "restaurant_id",  limit: 4
    t.string   "restaurantname", limit: 255
    t.string   "address",        limit: 255
    t.string   "tel",            limit: 255
    t.text     "description",    limit: 65535
    t.string   "lang",           limit: 255,   default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                null: false
  end

  create_table "restaurants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "restaurant_type", limit: 255
    t.string   "genre",           limit: 255
    t.string   "url",             limit: 255
    t.string   "fb",              limit: 255
    t.string   "mailaddr",        limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
```

And the Models.

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :restaurant_translations
end 

class RestaurantTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'restaurant_translations'
        belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

And then here's the controller which creates my headache.

```
class RestaurantController < ApplicationController
        def list
                @restaurants = Restaurant.includes(:restaurant_translations).where('restaurant_translations.lang = ?', "en").references(:restaurant_translations)
logger.debug @restaurants
        end
end
```

View file(.slim) is like this.

```
h1 = t :restraunt_list_title

table
  thead
    tr
      th = t :restraunt_list_type
      th = t :restraunt_list_name
      th = t :restraunt_list_url
      th = t :restraunt_list_genre
      th = t :restraunt_list_addr

  tbody
    - @restaurants.each do |restaurant|
      tr
        td = restaurant.restaurant_type
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.restaurantname
        td = link_to 'here', restaurant.url
        td = restaurant.genre
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.address


br
```

So, an error occurs 'No Method Error'. Tell me how to express association table parameters. Thanks in advance.

[image]

ps. After fixing the view as followed, the result is like this.
[image]

cf. restaurant_translation is like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to call the name method defined on the `restaurant_translations`, in that case you should be calling:

```
  tr
    td = restaurant.restaurant_type
    td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.name
    td = link_to 'here', restaurant.url
    td = restaurant.genre
    td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.address
```

However, a few corrections to your code,

1. You wouldn't need the `restaurant_id` column on restaurant, because that is already defined as `id` unless you want to also tie a `restaurant` to a `restaurant_translation` via a belongs_to association, in which case you'd need a `restaurant_translation_id` column.
2. I see that you're excluding the `id` column in `restaurant_translation` and yet adding it again, that seems a bit redundant, moreover if you want to take advantage of some advanced ActiveRecord features, you'd need an `id` column
3. You don't need to specify the table_name on `restaurant_translation` model as that is inferred by Rails
4. In your `restaurants_controller`, you're assigning `@restaurants` and reassigning it immediately to `restaurant_translations`. I don't know what you intended to do their, but I don't think that's right
5. Try to maintain a consistent name in your application, so that your future self can understand it. An example is the usage of `restraunt_list_type`, I guess you wanted to say `restaurant_list_type`

There could be others, but these are the ones my eyes caught immediately.

**UPDATE**
You should check your database to ensure that all your `restaurants` have at least a `restaurant_translation`. The error: `...for NilClass` means your `restaurant_translation` is an empty array. If you want to fetch all `restaurants` that have at least a `restaurant_translation`, then you should be using `joins vs includes` in your controller, as such:

```
Restaurant.joins(:restaurant_translations).where(restaurant_translations: { lang: "en"}).references(:restaurant_translations)
```

However, if you want to fetch all restaurants, with/without `restaurant_translations`, then I'd say you should go with the approach of the previous response to your question, using the `Object#try` method:

```
  tbody
    - @restaurants.each do |restaurant|
      tr
        td = restaurant.restaurant_type
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.try(:restaurantname)
        td = link_to 'here', restaurant.url
        td = restaurant.genre
        td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.try(:address)
```

Comment: Sorry for wrong description. I didn't write current controller.
I've updated current controller source code. Could you examine again?

Comment: Yeah, change the `td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.restaurantname` to `td = restaurant.restaurant_translations.first.name`

Comment: It still doesn't work. The error shows "undefined local variable or method `restaurant' "

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. My table definition was wrong. I update the definition above. Could you check it again?

Comment: Ok, I just updated the answer. The update should work, I guess

Comment: BTW, correct column name is 'restaurantname'. When I tried your idea, the result was still same.  The error shows "undefined local variable or method `restaurant' for #". How should I do? Sorry for bothering.

Comment: I've updated it. The snippet I pasted should be nested under the `tbody`

Comment: Thanks. Somehow, the error was gone out. But unfortunately, no data is shown the page. Could you check it latest image on the main topic? I've updated.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, if you want to fetch all `restaurants` that have at least a `restaurant_translation`, you should be using the `joins` approach, with the query I posted earlier: `Restaurant.joins(:restaurant_translations).where(restaurant_translations: { lang: "en"}).references(:restaurant_translations).distinct`

Comment: It looks like working after edited as you've mentioned.
But when the condition `{ lang: "en"})` to `{ lang: "ja"})` , results are same as before. I put table data. Why the condition doesn't work?

Comment: How's your opinion about that? Maybe the condition doesn't work.